# Difference between these 2 NSArrays

Tags: ios, nsarray

What is the difference between these two NSArray outputs using `NSLog`?

```
//Use to get all values from within Dictionary
    NSArray * values = [self.dict allValues];

    //Title
    self.namesArray = [values valueForKey:@"Imade"];
```

gives the following which is broken up into the KEY values they are stored in:

```
Names : (
        (
        tttt,
        tgrtg,
        trgrtgrtgrtgrtg
    ),
        (
        fcxczxc,
        zcxzc,
        asad
    ),
        (
        sdedw,
        frfefr
    )
)
```

and

```
self.colorArray= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Red", @"Yellow", @"Green",
                  @"Blue", @"Purpole", nil];
```

gives

```
Names : (
    Red,
    Yellow,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Purpole
)
```

Now I can populate a uiTableViewCell with the colored NSArray however I cannot with the Names NSArray. Why is this and how do I fix it? Do I need to break the namesArray down further and how do I do this? Im sorry if this is obvious.

If needed

```
 //Use to get Key Values from within Dictionary
   self.sectionArray = [self.dict allKeys];
```

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: As to the array being dumped after "Names:", the first is an array containing 3 arrays, while the second contains 5 strings.  (BTW, what color is "Purpole"?)

Comment: Whats the next stage after this? Each array within the array is seperated by the key value which is shown above the plist image.....and yeah no idea what color Purpole is! :)

Comment: Wasn't there a movie about that??  (Basically, we have no idea what you intend to do with the values in the first array, so no idea how to map it to the second scheme.  About all I can guess is that you could concatenate the arrays into one long array -- something that you should be able to figure out how to do with a quick peek at the NS(Mutable)Array spec.)

Comment: "Each array within the array is seperated by the key value which is shown above the plist image" -- all I see separating the arrays is a comma.  What "plist image"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the first array is an array of arrays, and the second one is an array of strings.

Comment: ok I understand that. How would I break it down further? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  Can you provide more info?

Comment: Trying to sort and group the plist shown above. Updated it